# CEP with Esper on Android?

Tags: android, esper, complex-event-processing

Are there any libraries that target CEP on Android devices, e.g. an Esper version for Android?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: it won't work out-of-the-box.

Have a look at this [discussion](http://old.nabble.com/Esper-on-Android-td29756424.html), it contains valuable information regarding Esper on android.

Answer (score -1):

We recently ported Esper to Android, and would very much appreciate if people tried it out
and provided us with feedback.

Have a look at Asper. 
https://github.com/plingpling/asper